# I'm getting 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource' even with all configured in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, axios

Even with all configurations made, when I try to access my DRF Api by `XMLHttpRequest`(using Axios), I'm getting the error below:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I use Postman I do not have any errors whatsoever.

*settings.py*

```
import os
import django_heroku
from decouple import config
from dj_database_url import parse as dburl

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = config('DEBUG')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ablog-back.herokuapp.com', 'localhost:3000']

# Application definition

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
#     'http://localhost:3000',
# )

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'ablogback.api',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'ablogback.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ablogback.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases
default_dburl = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')

DATABASES = {
    'default': config('DATABASE_URL', default=default_dburl, cast=dburl),
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Configure Django App for Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

*requirements.txt*

```
asgiref==3.2.10
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==3.0.8
django-cors-headers==3.4.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.5
python-decouple==3.3
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
static3==0.7.0
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

*axios request*

```
   const { url, method, onSuccess, onError } = action.payload

   try {
      const response = await axios.request({
         baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',
         url, //posts/
         method, //get
      })
      dispatch({
         type: onSuccess,
         payload: response.data
      })
   } catch(error) {
      console.log('error', error)
      dispatch({
         type: onError,
         payload: error
      })
   }
```

**EDIT1:**

This is what appears in Chrome Dev Tools/Network tab:

[Chrome Dev Tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNe0y.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding `127.0.0.1` or removing the `:3000` in ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: Tried it here, same error appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem: a missing `\` at the end of URL.

Comment: This post kinda helped me but I guess you meant forward slash?